# Color code autocomplete in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-autocomplete

Is there any way to change the colours of items in JQueries autocomplete? I want to have a roster system that will show different colours for people as to if they are away or not (that will show up as the user starts typing their name).

Code for input location:

```
<input id="autocomplete_test">
```

Code withing script tags (under $(function{}); to load when page loads):

```
var autoItems = ['First Name','Second Name','Another Name','Last One'];
$("#autocomplete_test").autocomplete({ source: autoItems });
```

Comment: Post code what you have achieved so far. Making a fiddle will help other to understand it better.

Comment: I added the code I had in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rMhVz/2/), you need to override `_renderItem` a bit:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: data
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);

    if (item.personal) {
        listItem.addClass("personal");
    }

    return listItem;
};
```

Add some `css` as well:

```
.personal { background-color: yellow; }
```

As this method is invoked when every item is rendered, you will be able to conditionally apply `css` `class` and then style it as you wish.

### EDIT

Comment: *Is there some way I can put the label into the input, but keep the value elsewhere?*

Yes, add some field (probably `hidden`) on the form (this one is not hidden for the sake of demo):

```
<input type='text' id='selected-value'/>
```

And then handle `select` event on `autocomplete`:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "input" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#selected-value" ).val( ui.item.value );

        return false;
      },
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);

    if (item.personal) {
        listItem.addClass("personal");
    }

    return listItem;
};
```

More info can be found on jQueryUI official page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rMhVz/1326/

Comment: This is awesome, that's what I wanted. I notice that that example puts the value (not the label) into the field when selected. Is there some way I can put the label into the input, but keep the value elsewhere? That way I can remember what name was selected from the id from the database when the form is submitted (but the user will just see the name in the field).

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I never thought to use the select event like that. Thanks heaps. BTW, I have upvoted but don't have the rep for it to show to the public yet.